# C# Fraction Calculator in Form

Tags: c#, forms, math

I'm trying to make a Fraction calculator in C# form.

I just cant get the math right 
This is the form 
[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dthae.png)

I want it to be able to calculate the result. 
When you type in 10/5 and 10/7 the result should be 3 3/7 
Or like this 
[How the result should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv3Dq.png)

What I get 
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSTGl.png)

This is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // result bottom

    {

        double box_In_Top_Left = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text); // Right UPPER BOX
        double box_In_Down_Left = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text); // Venstra Nederst string

        double box_In_Top_Right = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text); // Højre OP string
        double box_In_Down_Right = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text); // Højre Nederst String


        double whole = box_In_Down_Right * box_In_Down_Left; // Whole (Bottom Part of A fraction

        string whole_String = Convert.ToString(whole); // Converts the Whole to a string
        textBox7.Text = whole_String; // Shows the Answer in the box in the bottom right 

        double Calculation1 = box_In_Top_Left * box_In_Down_Right;  // Calculates the top lefts box result

        double Calculation2 = box_In_Top_Right * box_In_Down_Left; // Calculates the top right box Result

        double part = Calculation2 + Calculation1; // Calculates answer for the top box

        string part_String = Convert.ToString(part);


        if (part >= whole) // if the part is bigger then the whole
        {


            double Amount_Of_times_greater = part / whole;


            string string_Amount_Of_times_greater = Convert.ToString(Amount_Of_times_greater);

            double Ekstra_greatnes = part / Amount_Of_times_greater;

            textBox6.Text = string_Amount_Of_times_greater;
            double Part_Whole = (part / Amount_Of_times_greater);


            if (Ekstra_greatnes == whole)
            {

                Part_Whole = Part_Whole - whole;
                string string_Part_Whole = Convert.ToString(Part_Whole);

                textBox8.Text = string_Part_Whole;
            }
            else
            {
                string string_Part_Whole = Convert.ToString(Part_Whole);
                textBox8.Text = string_Part_Whole;
            }


        }
        else // For if the the part is not bigger then the whole
        {

            textBox8.Text = part_String; // Displayes part in the box in the right corner
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont see if your logic is right, but i see a first problem -> could be from the equal test: Ekstra_greatnes == whole

its difficult to compare double,

You can try using the decimal type which stores numbers in decimal notation. Thus 0.1 will be representable precisely
or you could use (seen on microsoft site) an epsilon value to compare the both values:

```
// Initialize two doubles with apparently identical values
double double1 = .333333;
double double2 = (double) 1/3;
// Define the tolerance for variation in their values
double difference = Math.Abs(double1 * .00001);

// Compare the values
// The output to the console indicates that the two values are equal
if (Math.Abs(double1 - double2) <= difference)
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are equal.");
else
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are unequal.");
```

Comment: I dont need decimal numbers the box 9 has to be with out decimals

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest storing the numerator and denominator separate. The best would be to create a new struct `Fraction` for that purpose. Then you can use the [euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the greatest common divisor. With that information in hand you can format your result.

```
string FormatFraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int gcd = Gcd(numerator, denominator );
    numerator /= gcd;
    denominator /= gcd;
    return $"{numerator/denominator} {Math.Abs(numerator/denominator)}";
}

int Gcd(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int a = Math.Abs(numerator);
    int b = Math.Abs(denominator);
    while (b != 0)
    {
        int temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }

    return a;
}
```

This code samples assumes, you're using a version of c# that supports string interpolation ($"<interpolated string>"). If not you can replace the last line of Format fraction with an string concatenation.

To add two fractions `a = a_1 / a_2` and `b = b_1 / b_2`you can use the simple formula `a + b = c = c_1 / c_2 = a_1 * b_2 + a_2 * b_1 / a_2 * b_2`